# Problem while trying to sideload ROM to my nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4

My nexus 4 was in boot-loop, so I tried to format and re-install android into my devices following instruction from a forum. I was able to reach the part trying to side-load ROM to my devices but unfortunately I failed. The file has been 100% sent over my device yet the installation was aborted. Anyone has any idea why it happens?? T.T

Comment: What were the instructions you followed? Please [edit] your question with more details so it is clearer what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "push" ADB command instead of side-loading to transfer the files.